# Proguard complains about missing classes in external JARs. How to solve this correctly?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate an Android 4+ app that uses Dropbox with Proguard in Eclipse. So far I have no experience with Proguard and thus I used different tutorials and answers here on SO to configure my `proguard-project.txt`:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
```

When I try to export the APK using the `File/Export.../Export Android Application/...` dialog the creation fails with an Proguard error:

```
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Note: there were 367 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.commons.logging.impl.ServletContextCleaner: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyPart
...
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
...
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: org.bouncycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: there were 223 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] Warning: there were 13 unresolved references to program class members.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-08-29 09:50:30 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

First Thing I tried was to add some `-libraryjars ...` commands:

```
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpclient-4.0.3.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/httpmime-4.0.3.jar'
-libraryjars 'F:/Path/To/Workspace/Third Party/Dropbox/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1/lib/json_simple-1.1.jar'
```

**This does not solve the problem.** In fact now there are 2468 duplicate class definitions (367 before...)

The next I tried is to ignore the warnings:

```
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.** 
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

This solves the problem! The creation of the APK now runs without any error. Fine... But I don't have a good feeling about this. **Is ignoring warnings really the best way to solve this issue?** Is this the "corrent" way of handling such issues?

When I run the APK on my device and try to use the Dropbox functions the app crashes. But this can be solved by adding the following:

```
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class com.dropbox.** {*;}
```

This protects the Dropbox code from being obfruscated. But again I am not sure if this is the right way to handle this.

So far the app seems to work fine with this configuration. But is there any way I can be sure Proguard did not broke anything (beside running a complete beta-test of every app function everytime the app is created?)

Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3rd party libraries are being processed twice. Add them to another folder in this case to `lib`
and add the following line to `proguard.cfg` file.

```
 -injars lib/dropbox.jar
```

See [Pro Guard Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

> Note: duplicate definition of program/library class
>
> Your program jars or library jars contain multiple definitions of the
>   listed classes. ProGuard continues processing as usual, only
>   considering the first definitions. The warning may be an indication of
>   some problem though, so it's advisable to remove the duplicates. A
>   convenient way to do so is by specifying filters on the input jars or
>   library jars. You can switch off these notes by specifying the
>   -dontnote option.

As indicated by the link to the [ProGuard Troubleshooting page](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember) in your console log, you should change the target in `project.properties` to a target that contains the missing classes. In this case: "android-18" or maybe "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18".

You can still specify a different minSdkVersion in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

You should *not* specify any `-libraryjars` options, since the Android build process already specifies those options for you -- you'll just see warnings about duplicate classes now. In fact, the Android build process specifies most other options for you as well.